# 'system.argumentexception' When uploading multipart

Tags: c#, windows-phone, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to post multipart data using System.Net.Http.HttpClient but when I am instanciating my content I am getting this exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Net.Http.DLL
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Net.Http.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
e: System.ArgumentException: The format of value '---###---' is invalid.
Parameter name: boundary
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent.ValidateBoundary(String boundary)
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartContent..ctor(String subtype, String boundary)
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent..ctor(String boundary)
   at RestClientUploadFoto.MultipartStackOverflow.<postMultipart>d__2.MoveNext()
```

- Why does it happen?

here is the method in where I am getting the exception:

```
public async Task postMultipart()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    // boundary      
    String boundary = "---###---"; // should never occur in your data

    // This is the postdata
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
    content.Add(new StringContent("12", Encoding.UTF8), "userId");
    content.Add(new StringContent("78", Encoding.UTF8), "noOfAttendees");
    content.Add(new StringContent("chennai", Encoding.UTF8), "locationName");
    content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "longitude");
    content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "latitude");

    Console.Write(content);
    // upload the file sending the form info and ensure a result.
    // it will throw an exception if the service doesn't return a valid successful status code
    await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
        .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
        {
            postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        });

}
```

Comment: Well what's the detail of the exception? Please post the complete stack trace including the message.

Comment: edited exception desc

Comment: Well that seems pretty self-explanatory, doesn't it? `---###---` is an invalid boundary. Have you tried using a different boundary string?

Comment: thanks, I had no idea what a boundary is, I am going to read it first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#` is invalid in a MIME boundary.

From [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046):

> The only mandatory global parameter for the "multipart" media type is
> the boundary parameter, which consists of 1 to 70 characters from a
> set of characters known to be very robust through mail gateways, and
> NOT ending with white space. (If a boundary delimiter line appears to
> end with white space, the white space must be presumed to have been
> added by a gateway, and must be deleted.)  It is formally specified
> by the following BNF:
>
> ```
> boundary := 0*69<bchars> bcharsnospace
>
> bchars := bcharsnospace / " "
>
> bcharsnospace := DIGIT / ALPHA / "'" / "(" / ")" /
>                  "+" / "_" / "," / "-" / "." /
>                  "/" / ":" / "=" / "?"
> ```

So basically, you should use a boundary string which doesn't contain a `#`. I'd suggest using one which doesn't contain hyphens either, just because the boundary *lines* will have hyphens anyway (at the start and end). Having them in the boundary as well is a bit confusing.

Unless you *need* a specific boundary, I suggest you just call the parameterless constructor, which will use a random GUID as the boundary.

Comment: do you know how to get the response body from there?

Comment: @eeadev: I don't know what you mean by "from there" but this sounds like it should be a new quesiton.

Comment: yes, right; here is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078917/how-to-get-response-body-from-httpclient-c-sharp-when-doing-multipart