# How to get response body from httpclient c# when doing multipart

Tags: c#, windows-phone, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to post multipart data using System.Net.Http.HttpClient,
the obtained response is 200 ok.

Here is the Method I used:

```
 public async Task postMultipart()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");


            // This is the postdata
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent( );
            content.Add(new StringContent("12", Encoding.UTF8), "userId");
            content.Add(new StringContent("78", Encoding.UTF8), "noOfAttendees");
            content.Add(new StringContent("chennai", Encoding.UTF8), "locationName");
            content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "longitude");
            content.Add(new StringContent("32.56", Encoding.UTF8), "latitude");

            Console.Write(content);
            // upload the file sending the form info and ensure a result.
            // it will throw an exception if the service doesn't return a valid successful status code
            await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) =>
                {
                    postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                });

        }
```

- How to obtain the response body from this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo Jon (one does not simply disagree with Jon), do not mix the async/await world with the pre-async/await (`ContinueWith`) world.

To get the response body as a string you need a 2nd await:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you're calling `PostAsync`, and awaiting the result... but then not doing anything with it. It's not clear why you're using `ContinueWith` either, when you're in an async world and can just handle it simply:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(fileUploadUrl, content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
// Now do anything else you want to with response,
// e.g. use its Content property
```

Comment: cant find the method to get the response body, response.content.toString() is returning System.Net.Http.StreamContent

Comment: @eeadev: Well did you look at the `HttpContent` class and its various methods?

Comment: thanks but I didnt have much time and I am not familiar with c# and MSDN so it was faster to ask u. sorry for being lazy